# Custom chrome extension not showing up?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I created a custom extension for chrome and it installed successfully and it works great but I don't see it in the menu at the options top right?

Do I need to include something else in the `manifest.json`, or do I have to code something more that needs to show up since I don't have any options, its just a Tampermonkey script converted into an extensions.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Name..",
    "version": "0.7..",
    "description": "Desc..",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "author": "...",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "exclude_globs": [],
        "include_globs": ["*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "myScript.user.js"],
        "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "converted_from_user_script": true
}
```

Comment: If you are not going to actually use the capability provided with `include_globs` (i.e. matching everything with `"*"`) or `exclude_globs`, then it would be better not to include them in your *manifest.json*. If they are not included, then the processing to match them will not need to occur on every page.

Comment: If you don't have options, or actions, why are you looking for a UI interface to be showing something that does not exist? Where *exactly* are you expecting to see "it"? What are you expecting to see (e.g. text, an icon)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

In my case i needed to add:

```
"browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": { 
        "128": "icon_128.png" 
    },
    "default_title": "title..."
}
```